# Calculate $\lim _{ n\to \infty } \int _{ |x|<n }{ \int _{ |y|<n }{\sin(x^2+y^2)\,dx\,dy } } $

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

$$\lim _{ n\to \infty } \int _{ |x|<n }{ \int _{ |y|<n }{ \sin(x^2+y^2)\,dx\,dy } }$$

Seeing that $n\to \infty$ I deduce that yes $|x|<n$ and $|y|<n$ then $-\infty<x<\infty$ and $-\infty<y<\infty$

But I don't know if I can use these limits.

Another observation I see is in the argument of the function $\sin(x^2+y^2)$ Which makes me think that I can use polar coordinates.

Any suggestions on how to calculate such a limit? How could you write the limits of the integral?

Comment: The integral can be reduced to $\pi \int_0^\infty sin(u)du$ which does not exist.

Comment: In particular it does not converge?

Comment: It is slightly messy when switching to polar coordinates because of the shape difference.  The integral behaves like the $u$ integral $\int _0^{n^2}$, which oscillates, not converges.

Comment: @herbsteinberg: sometimes the "shape difference" leads to unexpected results ;)

Answer (score 2):

The integral under the limit is equal to $2 C_n S_n$, where $$C_n=\int_{-n}^n\cos t^2\,dt,\qquad S_n=\int_{-n}^n\sin t^2\,dt$$ (which is easy to see using $\sin(a+b)=\sin a\cos b+\cos a\sin b$).

And it is [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral#Limits_as_x_approaches_infinity) that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}C_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}S_n=\sqrt{\pi/2}$. Hence the given limit is $\pi$.